# my changes on my Laravel config file does not work

Tags: php, laravel, configuration

I have been changing some configurations in my config/cors.php and these changes are saved and they been written in my bootstrap/config.php file, but it does not work.

For example I changed 'allowed_methods' from *  to POST but GET method still work on my code(my code is on my local server).

I'm going to add a picture of my config/cors.php for you to see if I'm doing something wrong.

thanks.

[image: my config/cors.php file]

Answer (score 1):

php artisan optimize:clear
and then restart your localserver

Comment: I did that but still doesn't  work

Comment: Try php artisan config:cache in this case

Comment: I did that too same result